# How do I make 2 or more horizontal divs stack into a vertical div when the user shrinks the browser window?

Tags: css, html, layout, liquid

I have 2 divs on same row, each with a width of 50% and a float: left. I would like them to stack one on top of the other if the user is viewing the page from a smart-phone. Right now, the divs remain on the same row even if the browser window is narrowed to 300px or if viewed from a smart-phone.

Comment: give the divs a min-width, e.g. 150px

Answer (score 2):

Media queries is the way to go. I'd go with a mobile-first approach, and add media queries to scale up the design. I.e, start with the divs *not* floating, and add float and width when the screen estate reaches a certain size:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <p>This is column 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <p>This is column 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
/* CSS */
.wrapper {
    /* Ensure wrapper contains the columns, even when they are floated, by
       creating a new Block formatting context */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
    /* Ensure we have some margins when the columns are collapsed, or 
       other content is displayed below. */
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

/* Edit the min-width condition to match your desired breakpoint. */
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .wrapper .column {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jPgWL/

Comment: Hello Patrik, thank you very much. This fix works perfectly! I never paid much attention to @media because I always thought that it was most useful for css as it relates to printing web pages. Thank you  :)

Comment: @AlexWilliams Don't forget to accept this answer (click the green "wink" beneath the upvote button).

Comment: Sorry, it says that my reputation must be at least 15 to upvote. Right now I am only 11 :(

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  #wrapper {width: 100%;}
  .content {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  #wrapper {width: 100%;}
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: which would be a cleaner solution than just adding min-width as it also increases witdth to 100% if the div is wrapped