# How can I make 3 columns responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm attempting to make a responsive 3 column layout so when a visitor of the website shrinks the window's width, the columns become aligned vertically instead of horizontally **e.g.** on this website: http://outdatedbrowser.com/

I've tried using media queries but the columns just disappear as soon as I shrink the window width. **P.S. I can only purely use CSS and HTML, I can't use any sort of framework as this is a college assignment I'm doing**

I have 3 columns:

```
  <div class="showcaseContainer">
    <div class="col1"><p>The Raven's Claw</p></div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3"></div>
  </div>
```

Below is the CSS

```
.showcaseContainer {
    margin:  10px auto;
    width: 100%;
    }

.showcaseContainer > div {
    width: 33%;
    }

.col1 {
    width: 23.8%;
    height: 298px;
    float: left;

    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: url('')
}
.col2 {
    width: 23.8%;
    height: 298px;
    float: right;

    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: purple;
    background-image: url('')
}

.col3 {
    width: 23.8%;
    height: 298px;
    margin: auto; /* mid column */

    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('')
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make 2 or more horizontal divs stack into a vertical div when the user shrinks the browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265530/how-do-i-make-2-or-more-horizontal-divs-stack-into-a-vertical-div-when-the-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexbox` for this

```css
.showcaseContainer {
  display: flex;
}
.showcaseContainer > div {
  flex: 1;
}

.col1 {
    height: 298px;
    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: url('')
}
.col2 {
    height: 298px;
    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: purple;
    background-image: url('')
}

.col3 {
    height: 298px;
    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('')
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .showcaseContainer{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showcaseContainer">
    <div class="col1"><p>The Raven's Claw</p></div>
    <div class="col2"><p>Col 2</p></div>
    <div class="col3"><p>Col 3</p></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can't use any sort of framework unfortunately! Thanks for the idea though @LGSon

Comment: @SterlingKing This is no framework, this is plain CSS and html

Comment: Oh ok! I never knew that! Thanks @LGSon

Comment: @SterlingKing Updated answer with your `col*` classes

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries - You are also declaring the same rules across your column classes for the most part - You can simplify that to make your code run more efficient.

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b3c2jnrj/2/)

```css
.showcaseContainer {
    margin:  10px auto;
    width: 100%;
    }

.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 10px); /* Divide by 3 columns and subtract 10px for border size */
    height: 298px;
    float: left;

    border-left: 10px solid #000;
}

.col1 {
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: url('');
}
.col2 {
    background-color: purple;
    background-image: url('');
}
.col3 {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('');
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col1,
  .col2,
  .col3 {
    /* Specify your width rule here - Examples */
    /* width: 100%; - Having 1 column */
    width: calc(50% - 10px); /* Having 2 columns */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showcaseContainer">
    <div class="col1"><p>The Raven's Claw</p></div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3"></div>
  </div>
```