# Responsive Column for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, multiple-columns, responsive

I have 3 columns created in html. It all looks good but the column with Twitter embedded will not stay the same size when the browser is reduced in size or when viewed on mobile.

Mobile View
[image: Mobile view]

Desktop View 1 
[image: Desktop View]

Desktop View 2

[image: Desktop View 2]

No matter what I do its always either too big or too small. I have it in a

```
<div class="twitterContainer">
```

Because the twitter feed kept spilling out past the border.

I've tried media queries as seen in this answer

[Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265530/how-do-i-make-2-or-more-horizontal-divs-stack-into-a-vertical-div-when-the-user)

Here's my latest code:

```
<!-- wp:columns {"columns":3} -->
<div class="wp-block-columns has-3-columns">
<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="column">
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>News</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":482,"align":"center","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<div class="wp-block-image"><figure class="aligncenter"><a href="http://www.patricianprimaryschool.ie/home/newsletter/"><img src="http://www.patricianprimaryschool.ie/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Newsletter.png" alt="" class="wp-image-482"/></a> . 
</figure></div>
<!-- /wp:image --></div>
        <!-- /wp:column --></div>

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="column">
<div class="wp-block-column">
<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Calendar</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:image {"id":481,"align":"center","linkDestination":"custom"} -->
<div class="wp-block-image"><figure class="aligncenter"><a href="http://www.patricianprimaryschool.ie/home/school-calender/"><img src="http://www.patricianprimaryschool.ie/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/SchoolCalendar-01-1024x1024.png" alt="" class="wp-image-481"/></a></figure></div>
<!-- /wp:image --></div>
        <!-- /wp:column --></div>

<div class="column">
<div class="twitterContainer">
<!-- wp:column -->

<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Follow Us</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:html -->
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="300" data-theme="light" href="https://twitter.com/PPSNewbridge?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by PPSNewbridge</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- /wp:html --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /wp:columns -->
```

*edit CSS Added

```
.wp-block-columns {
margin: 112px;
}

.wp-block-column {
border: 2px solid #354063;
padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? TIA

**Edit

[image: Image mis alignment]

Comment: Would need some css to see that.. at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So you have your `wp-block-column` inside your `twitterContainer`. Remove the inner container and put the 2 classes together in 1 div.

So this:

```
<div class="twitterContainer">
<!-- wp:column -->

<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Follow Us</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:html -->
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="300" data-theme="light" href="https://twitter.com/PPSNewbridge?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by PPSNewbridge</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- /wp:html --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div class="wp-block-column twitterContainer">
<!-- wp:column -->

<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Follow Us</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:html -->
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="300" data-theme="light" href="https://twitter.com/PPSNewbridge?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by PPSNewbridge</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- /wp:html -->
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
```

Comment: Adding min-width: 220px; to my css solved the mobile sizing error however the desktop column size is still different sizes as seen in the example image above "Desktop View 2"

Comment: Did you also add `max-width: 550px;`?

Comment: Ya adding 'max-width: 550px;' makes all 3 columns align to the left side of the page leaving the right side of the page empty.

Comment: Aah. Yes. Then it's not the columns you want to change. Try using an inner container inside each column. Set the inner container to `min-width: 220px; max-width: 550px; margin: auto;`. So you would have a parent container (the column) that stretches over 33%, and a smaller container inside that is centered inside the parent container.

Comment: Hah I see. The solution is actually a lot closer.. I will change my answer.

Comment: That worked except for a slight miss alignment in the first column as you can see on screenshot above in edited answer.